# Despite the token attached, it still returns the 405Method Not Allowed error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, postman, http-status-code-405

I want use JWT Authentication with ASP.NET Core 2 Web API.
I have obtained the token but I cannot access the action /api/values.
Please show me where I was wrong.

After login I have token key.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv5mx.jpg)

And 405 err
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYkIJ.jpg)

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; private set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ===== Add our DbContext ========
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressUseValidationProblemDetailsForInvalidModelStateResponses = true;
        }); ;

        // ===== Add Identity ========
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUserModel, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(
            options =>
            {
                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3;

                // Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();
        services.AddTransient<IJwtService, JwtService>();

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "ToDo API",
                Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
                TermsOfService = "None",
                Contact = new Contact
                {
                    Name = "Shayne Boyer",
                    Email = string.Empty,
                    Url = "https://twitter.com/spboyer"
                },
                License = new License
                {
                    Name = "Use under LICX",
                    Url = "https://example.com/license"
                }
            });
            c.OperationFilter<AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "{name}");

            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

JwtService:

```
public class JwtService : IJwtService
    {
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
        public JwtService(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Take user name, device, roles and generate encoded token.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName"></param>
        /// <param name="device"></param>
        /// <param name="roles"></param>
        /// <returns>token string</returns>
        public string GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, string device, IList<string> roles = null)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.System, device)
            };

            if (roles?.Any() == true)
            {
                foreach (string role in roles)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }
            }

            // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
            JwtSecurityToken jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _appSettings.JwtSetting.JwtIssuer,
            audience: _appSettings.JwtSetting.JwtAudience,
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(_appSettings.JwtSetting.JwtExpireDays),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JwtSetting.JwtKey)),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );

            string encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

            return encodedJwt;
        }
    }
```

AccountService

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUserModel> _userManager;
    private readonly IJwtService _jwtService;

    public AccountService(UserManager<ApplicationUserModel> userManager, IJwtService jwtService)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _jwtService = jwtService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create new user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<CreateUserResponseModel> Create(CreateUserRequestModel user)
    {
        // Request model
        ApplicationUserRequestModel request = new ApplicationUserRequestModel();

        // Request model to data model
        ApplicationUserModel applicationUser = request.CreateUserRequestModelToApplicationUserDateModel(user);

        // Timestamping
        applicationUser.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // Create new user
        IdentityResult newUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(
            applicationUser,
            user.Password);

        if (newUser.Succeeded)
        {
            // Response model
            ApplicationUserResponseModel response = new ApplicationUserResponseModel();

            // Return created user
            return response.ApplicationUserDataModelToCreateUserRequestMode(applicationUser);

        }

        // Error
        CreateUserResponseModel errorResponse = new CreateUserResponseModel();

        if (newUser.Errors != null)
        {
            errorResponse.Errors = new List<ErrorModel>();

            foreach (IdentityError error in newUser.Errors)
            {
                errorResponse.Errors.Add(
                    new ErrorModel()
                    {
                        ErrorCode = error.Code,
                        ErrorDescription = error.Description
                    });
            }
        }

        return errorResponse;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Validate user id, password then generate token (as mean of login)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="login"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<LoginResponseModel> Login(LoginRequestModel login)
    {

        LoginResponseModel response = new LoginResponseModel();

        // Check user name
        ApplicationUserModel user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(login.UserName);

        if (user != null)
        {

            // Check password
            bool isPasswordOk = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, login.Password);

            if (isPasswordOk)
            {
                // Get roles
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                // If sucess then generate token
                response.Token = _jwtService.GenerateEncodedToken(user.UserName, login.Device, roles);

                return response;
            }

            response.Errors = new List<ErrorModel>()
                {
                    new ErrorModel()
                    {
                        ErrorCode = "400",
                        ErrorDescription = "Invalid password"
                    }
                };

            return response;
        }

        response.Errors = new List<ErrorModel>()
            {
                new ErrorModel()
                {
                    ErrorCode = "400",
                    ErrorDescription = "Invalid user"
                }
            };

        return response;
    }
}
```

AccountsController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    public AccountsController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("/Account/CreateUser")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CreateUserResponseModel>> Create([FromBody] CreateUserRequestModel user)
    {
        var response = await _accountService.Create(user);

        return response;
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("/Account/Login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<LoginResponseModel>> Login([FromBody] LoginRequestModel login)
    {

        var response = await _accountService.Login(login);

        return response;
    }
}
```

ValuesController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks for watching.

Comment: How is your Values controller defined? You are not showing us the action you are trying to access. I suspect that the /api/values endpoint is `HttpGet`. The `405 Method Not Allowed` error code means exactly that. You are trying to access a resource with a wrong HTTP method (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc)

Comment: api/value is not POST

Comment: I have added the source code of ValuesController. Even when I put the [Authorize] attribute on Get, the error code returned the same.

Comment: How do you send request?

Comment: @Uriil. I use postman to send requests.  Header parameters like the image above I attached.

Comment: Do you specify Body for POST request? I don't see this part of request on image.